# Is it ok to cook pork for others?

Tags: food

Assalamu alaikum. I am a muslim and i am an aspiring chef,my question is that ,is it ok to cook pork for others if ones profession demands it . Pls help me with this and jazakallah khair

Comment: Please Google your question before asking. [Your question is answered here](https://www.quora.com/Should-I-cook-pork-if-my-profession-demands-it-if-I-am-a-Chef-and-also-a-Muslim)

Answer (score -2):

Yes , in order to make a living for yourself you can serve pork. As long as your not serving to your own children and feeding them . As minors they are your accountability . Yourself eating is also something you will be held accountable for. Serving to Muslims under deceiving circumstances will be something wrong. If you are serving to people (non Muslim ) who ask you while your working for them , your not accountable for their actions . Your simply a facilitator to a choice that they make.

Allah allows us to even consume swine if there is no choice but you should always choose the halal way of circumstances allow it .

I’m in a country where there is no access to halal food , very few places serve it. So I choose to stay in the guidelines . I eat fish or vegan or salads. If your circumstances allow it , always choose the halal way to have more content heart and life.

May Allah bless you